# Import table using IMPORTXML

Tags: google-sheets, importxml

I am trying to import a table from the lower part of following website to Google Sheets:
http://www.etnet.com.hk/www/tc/warrants/search_cbbc_hsi.php

I used the formula:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.etnet.com.hk/www/tc/warrants/search_cbbc_hsi.php","//td//a")
```

but the output is messy and contains many other data outside the table.

Anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have forgotten to mention what you would consider tidy, but it should be easier to handle your data (assumed to be starting in A1) with a formula such as:

```
=offset(A1,int(2*((row()-1)/2)),0)
```

in B1 and the same again in C1 with an extra `+1` immediately before the `,0` - both copied down to suit.

[OFFSET](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093379)
[INT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093490)
[ROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093316)